# I want to count the total team score for every team but I keep getting the total score for all the teams so how do i do that?

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop

Below is my ruby programming exercise for arrays and i am require to use for loop in this exercise. I want to calculate the total team score for every team but i keep getting this in the command prompt:

```
Team 1
1
2
3
4
Team 2
1
2
3  
4
the total score is 20
```

but I want to get something like:

```
Team 1
1
2
3
4
the total score is 10
Team 2
1
2
3  
4
the total score is 10
```

Below is my code so far and the problem lies at def teamscore()

```
require './input_functions'
PLAYERS = 4


# This function will prompt user to enter the individual
# score of each player for all teams
# (Each team consists of four players).
# All the input will be stored in the array
  def input(noteam, arrayb)
    for x in 0..noteam-1
       arrayb[x] = Array.new(PLAYERS)
         for y in 0..PLAYERS-1
           puts "Team " + (x+1).to_s
           arrayb[x][y] = read_integer("Enter Score for individual player: ")
         end
      end
  end



   # Print the entire array to the screen in matrix form.
   def disp_arr(myarray, row,col)
    for x in 0..myarray.length-1
    row+=1
    puts "Team " + row.to_s
     for y in 0..PLAYERS-1
       puts myarray[x][y]
     end    
    end     


    end


    # This function calculates the total score for one team,
    # and return the total score for that team
    def teamscore (arrayc)
    sum = 0
     for x in 0..arrayc.length-1
      for y in 0..PLAYERS-1
       sum+=arrayc[x][y]

      end
     end
     sum


    end


  def main

   # declare needed variables or constants
   num = 0
   num2=0
   # prompt user to enter total number of teams
   teams = read_integer(" How many teams : ")
   arraya = Array.new(teams)
 # call input(...) function
 input(teams,arraya)
 # call the disp_arr(...) function

  disp_arr(arraya,num,num2)

 # call the teamscore(...) function for every team

 r=teamscore(arraya)

 # and display the team score for each team
  puts "the total score is " + r.to_s

 end

 main
```

This is the code for input_functions

```
 # Display the prompt and return the read integer
def read_integer prompt
value = read_string(prompt)
value.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rewriting it in OOP style, so it would be easier to maintain:

```
class Team
  attr_reader :players, :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @players = []
  end

  def add_player(player)
    @players << player
  end

  def total_score
    players.sum(&:score)
  end
end

class Player
  attr_accessor :score

  def initialize(score)
    @score = score
  end
end

class Cli
  attr_reader :number_of_teams, :number_of_players, :teams

  def initialize
    @teams = []
  end

  def request_user_input
    puts "How many teams: "
    number_of_teams = read_integer
    puts "How many players in each team: "
    number_of_players = read_integer

    number_of_teams.times do |teams_index|
      team = Team.new("Team #{teams_index + 1}")
      puts team.name
      number_of_players.times do
        puts "Enter Score for individual player: "
        score = read_integer
        player = Player.new(score)
        team.add_player(player)
      end
      teams << team
    end
  end

  def print_scores
    teams.each do |team|
      puts team.name
      team.players.each do |player|
        puts player.score
      end
      puts "the total score is #{team.total_score}"
    end
    nil
  end

  private

    def read_integer
      gets.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i
    end
end
```

Then call `Cli` to run the program

```
cli = Cli.new
cli.request_user_input
cli.print_scores
```

It works like this:

```
> cli = Cli.new
 => #<Cli:0x000055d14a391d10 @teams=[]> 
2.5.1 :324 > cli.request_user_input
How many teams: 
2
How many players in each team: 
4
Team 1
Enter Score for individual player: 
1
Enter Score for individual player: 
2
Enter Score for individual player: 
3
Enter Score for individual player: 
4
Team 2
Enter Score for individual player: 
1
Enter Score for individual player: 
2
Enter Score for individual player: 
5
Enter Score for individual player: 
6
 => 2 
2.5.1 :325 > cli.print_scores
Team 1
1
2
3
4
the total score is 10
Team 2
1
2
5
6
the total score is 14
```